# Accessing .count() and .all() inside the model

Tags: django, django-models

Can I access .all() or . count () inside the model in models.py file?

I'm working on a poll app and I want on field value dynamically to save the .count() of it's many to many field.

Comment: Please post your model and more information

Comment: class Question(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField()
    voters = models.ManyToManyField(to=User, blank=True, related_name='voters')
    impression = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=impression_choices, blank=True, null=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(to=User, related_name='likes', blank=True)
    total_likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

Answer (score 0):

No, you can use `.count()` and `.all()` in models as these are query methods https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/

but you can define the method in models

For example

```
def count(self):
  # ...
  return t_count
```

And define your logic for count

Might it help you? If not please let me know

Comment: Thank U sir, I found the way how to use let me share with you.                                                            
    `def total_likes(self):
        return self.Question.objects.count()`

Comment: Please approve the answer if u find it useful. so it is easy for somebody to assure it works. If not, please disapprove.